# TSQL Bloqueos concurrentes o por consulta

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dos procedimientos almacenados que insertan o actualizan la misma tabla, entre otra serie de operaciones. Ambos procedimientos son de este estilo:

```
BEGIN TRAN

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TABLA_TEMPORAL
    CREATE TABLE #TABLA_TEMPORAL(referencia NVARCHAR(100), stock INTEGER)

    INSERT INTO #TABLA_TEMPORAL(referencia, stock)
    SELECT referencia, stock
    FROM TABLA_PIEZAS WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
    WHERE...

    --SE REALIZAN CÁLCULOS SOBRE #TABLA_TEMPORAL.stock....
    --EN ESTE MOMENTO OTRO PROCESO PODRÍA MODIFICAR TABLA_PIEZAS.stock, INVALIDANDO LOS DATOS DEL SELECT DE ESTA TRANSACCIÓN.

    UPDATE TABLA_PIEZAS WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
    SET TABLA_PIEZAS.stock = #TABLA_TEMPORAL.stock
    FROM TABLA_PIEZAS
        INNER JOIN #TABLA_TEMPORAL ON TABLA_PIEZAS.referencia = #TABLA_TEMPORAL.referencia

COMMIT
```

Para evitar que otro proceso modifique TABLA_PIEZAS e invalide los datos de este SELECT, le he añadido también el WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE) al select, de manera que los registros quedan protegidos.

Mi duda es si ambos procesos saltan de forma simultánea... ¿Los bloqueos a las filas se realizan de forma aislada por cada transacción o se van bloqueando a la vez, y cada transacción bloquea unos u otros? Porque esto podría generar un interbloqueo.

Es decir, se toma el primer SELECT que llegue y se bloquean todas sus filas y después las del siguiente SELECT (si es que se pueden bloquear) o se van bloqueando las de los dos SELECT a la vez. ¿Cómo funciona el gestor de bloqueos de MSSQL?